# How to respond for partial failure in micro-services gateway?

Tags: api, http, microservices, api-design, http-status-codes

I am seeking your opinion on the following scenario. Imagine following microservices system.

1. Microservice - A: This does some work/task A
   `responseA: { key: value}`
2. Microservice - B: This does some work/task B
   `responseB: { key: value}`
3. Gateway/Aggregator: This invokes Microservices A & B in parallel and combines the results.
   `gatewayResponse: { responseA: { key: value}, responseB: {key: value}}`

In an ideal scenario where both services are successful, then the above response "gatewayResponse" makes sense, i.e. HTTP STATUS CODE 200

My question is more regarding partial failure. Let's say service B is down or while executing a request it failed due to any reason, but service A is totally okay. In such a case how "gatewayResponse" should look like and what should be the HTTP STATUS CODE?

Solution - HTTP STATUS CODE 200 / should it be some other STATUS CODE??

```
gatewayResponse: {
 responseA: {
    key: value
 },
 responseB: {
    error: {
      "some details about error"
    }
 }

}
```

I would appreciate your response on this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: One does not simply put a gateway in front of two webservices and call it microservices, contrary to popular belief. Microservices are a design principle. You are the only one who can answer this. What will it mean for this to partially fail? Should the client retry the request at a later time? Is one operation dependent on the other?

Comment: Hello @CodeCaster
Thank you for your response. As I mentioned in my post, a gateway is more of an aggregator here and NO both services are not dependent on each other. Both services are invoked in parallel.

Comment: Then the right pattern would have been to do 2 separate request, instead of combining them.